# How is this struct definition made private?

Tags: c, struct, typedef

In some vendor code I see structs used as objects with pointers to them as handles in a header file as follows

hdr.h

```
typedef struct _FOO_Obj_ {
    uint16_t x;
} FOO_Obj;

typedef struct FOO_Obj * FOO_Handle;
```

src.c

```
#include <hdr.h>
void main (void) {
    FOO_Handle bar = FOO_init(); // No error
    bar->x = 5;    // Error: pointer to incomplete class type
}
```

This allows the file that includes such header files to use the type `FOO_Handle` but somehow prevents access to the members of the `FOO_Obj`, e.g. at the marked line in src.c... what is happening here??

For comparison, I would previously have used the following:

```
struct FOO_Obj {
    uint16_t x;
};
typedef struct FOO_Obj * FOO_Handle;
```

With this method, I could also do:

```
FOO_Obj y;
FOO_Handle bar (void) {  // unintentional bicycle pun ftw
    return &y;
}
```

But with the first method, this same function causes an error that the return type doesn't match???

Comment: If `FOO_Handle` is a type name, then `FOO_Handle = FOO_init();` shouldn't compile.

Comment: @YuHao Whoops, good spot, edited to add FOO_Handle variable name `bar`

Comment: this is called the opaque pointer pattern, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer

Comment: In the vendor code: Where is `struct FOO_Obj` defined?

Comment: @alk It's not, hence my confusion and thus my question

Comment: @Claptrap I see that this is the same pattern, but Im still not entirely clear on how it works in this case. For example, how does the `typedef struct FOO_Obj * FOO_Handle;` line work when there is no struct `FOO_Obj`? Furthermore, as this hides the "pointer-ness" of `FOO_Handle` is this code smell?

Comment: What is the `typedef` in the `.h` file good for? Are you sure that you copied things correctly? As you use it here, it makes not much sense. The `typedef` named `FOO_Obj` and the `struct FOO_Obj` are two completely unrelated things for the compiler. If somewhere in the user code `FOO_Obj` would be used to allocate and object that is treated as `struct FOO_Obj`, this would be undefined behavior.

Comment: Ahok, so I assume you also do not have the code implementing the vendor's `FOO_init()`?

Comment: @JensGustedt Yup, definitely the same code copied. Checked about 8-9 times now :)

Comment: @Toby true, I have retracted my close vote.

Comment: @alk an exmaple _init() from vendor code is 
`FOO_Handle FOO_init(void *pMemory, const size_t numBytes) { FOO_Handle fooHandle; fooHandle = (FOO_Handle)pMemory; return(fooHandle);}`
The members match up to particular registers that start at pMemory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't get it how they intend to use this, but here is a general rule that applies to such stuff if you want to go beyond the usual "opaque pointer" method which just uses a pointer to `struct` without defining the `struct`.

You may have different `struct` definitions in different compilation units (here the user code and the library) that are passed around as parameters to functions between the units, but

- their structure must be exactly the same, same types same order
- if the `struct` has a tagname in one unit it also must have one in the other
- if in both units there is a `struct` tag, this tag must be exactly the same

Otherwise (one `struct` with tag and one without, or different tag names) the behavior is undefined. Think e.g of link time optimization to see why this might be important.

There is another rule that applies in connection with C++ that I recently learnt the hard way. There, the C++ name for name mangling is either the `struct` tag if it exists, or the `typename` if it doesn't. So if you have `struct` without tag, you'd better have the `typedef` names agree, too.

Another, minor, point in the code that you found is that names starting with underscore are reserved in file scope, they should not be used.

Answer (score 2):

The type of the structure is `struct _FOO_Obj_`, after the `typedef`, it has an alias `FOO_Obj`. However, there's no such type as `struct FOO_Obj`.

So this other `typedef` line

```
typedef struct FOO_Obj * FOO_Handle;
```

should be either

```
typedef FOO_Obj * FOO_Handle;
```

or

```
typedef struct _FOO_Obj_ * FOO_Handle;
```

Comment: This is what I initially though, yet it compiles and works as the vender intends...

Answer (score 1):

Generally, any time you mention a struct type that doesn't exist yet, you create it. If you specify the contents of the struct at the same time, it's created as a *complete* type, otherwise it's *incomplete*. Complete struct types allow the use of the `.` and `->` operators. Incomplete struct types don't.

A struct type can be created with a declaration that does nothing else:

```
struct foo; /* Creates an incomplete type called "struct foo") */
struct bar { int x,y; }; /* Creates a complete type called "struct bar" */
```

Or it can be created with a declaration that also declares some variables.

```
struct foo *p; /* Creates an incomplete type called "struct foo"
                  and a variable of type "struct foo *" called "p" */
struct bar { int x,y; } v, *p; /* Creates a complete type called "struct foo"
                                  and a variable of type "struct foo" called "v"
                                  and a variable of type "struct foo *" called "p" */
```

Note that you can't just say `struct foo v;` unless `struct foo` already exists as a complete type. Incomplete types have unknown sizes, so the compiler wouldn't know how much space to allocate for `p`. But pointers to structs have a known size even if the struct itself doesn't, so `struct foo *p;` works fine with an incomplete type.

Or you can create a struct at the same time you create a typedef:

```
typedef struct foo f, *fptr; /* Creates an incomplete type with 2 names:
                                "struct foo" and "f"; also makes "fptr" an alias
                                for the type "struct foo *" */
typedef struct bar { int x,y; } b, *bptr; /* Creates a complete type with 2 names:
                                             "struct bar" and "b"; also makes "bptr"
                                             an alias for the type "struct bar *" */
```

The version where you declare a struct type and a variable of that type at the same time even works inside the parameter list of a function declaration:

```
int dosomething(struct foo *p) { ... }
int dosomethingelse(struct foo *p) { ... }
```

If `struct foo` doesn't already exist, the above code creates a type `struct foo` for the first function, and another type `struct foo` for the second function. Each one has a separate scope. They're not the same type. This is not something you'll ever do on purpose.